# Insertions into a max heap with atmost one swap

Tags: algorithm, priority-queue, max-heap

Is there a algorithm to perform insertions into a heap with atmost one swap (O(log n) comparisons are allowed)

Answer (score 1):

No.

Consider this heap:

[image: max heap]

Suppose you add 200. Obviously it will have to become the new root.

So where does 100 go? It can't become a child of 3, and that's what it would have to do if you only have one swap.